# When will my resizing finish in amazon EMR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I am trying to resize the number of core-nodes. Initially, it was two, then I resized it to 10. At that time, it worked well. Now, I'm trying to increase it to 100. It becomes 15, then it doesn't increase any more. The status still says resizing after two hours.

I followed this instruction one hour ago: https://aws.amazon.com/ko/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/force-resize-emr-cluster/ But, this doesn't seem to work. And the command per se is old.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

EMR is unable to upsize if the machines are not available.

Did you check your node type and quota ?

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-instance-limit/

There could be other processes in your organization using the machines from the same quota.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I requested to increase New Reserved Instances per month. Do you know whether I should increase Running Dedicated Hosts? They are zeros now. As I can use dedicated hosts, I guess zero means infinite.

Comment: @Calee Reserved Instances are purely a billing discount. They will not impact your ability to launch Amazon EC2 instances. However, there are limits to the amount of Amazon EC2 resources you have running simultaneously. Go to "Service Quotas" in the AWS management console (it's an option just like EC2 and S3) and view the quotes for **EC2**. You can request the limits to be increased.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes, I went to "Service Quotas", and requested to increase "New Reserved Instances per month" quota under Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud page.

Comment: Please note that Reserved Instances are a financial commitment for 1-3 years. **This is unlikely to be what you actually want!!** The limits that are impacting you right now would likely be **Running Instances**, defined as _"Maximum number of vCPUs assigned to the Running On-Demand Standard instances"_ of particular Instance Familities.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thank you. You are totally right. Let me try it.